# Sharing static files in Django server with webpack-quasar

Tags: python, django, webpack, quasar

I have done a project with Django as backend and quasar as frontend. I want to publish the quasar-frontend side of the project in the Django server. So, I have build production on a quasar with webpack, and I get the necessary folders with production files such as CSS, js. And I have separated them into static files and index.html due to the Django framework structure. Django server shares the static files with extra folders like this example: '/static/somenestedfolder/'. So when the Django server shares the index.html file to the client, the client can not get the static js and CSS files with error 404 not found. For example, the client requests the address to get some js files: http://127.XX.XX.XX:8000/js/some.js, but the static files are located in http://127.XX.XX.XX:8000/static/js/some.js. So, I just want to add the '/static' (or some nested folder), when the webpack build production files.

Or the sharing-static-files method is incorrect:
a) Should I use the python webpack-loader module?;
b) there are any methods to do it?
c) Can I use it on production mode the Django too?

Answer (score 0):

I have done it manually by adding 'static/somenestedfolder/' into two places in app.js file: `function s(e){return c.p+"static/spa/js/"+({}[e]||e)+"."+{1:"8855391b",3:"aef3bbdb",4:"e185e379",5:"6e19df14",6:"a2e4728f",7:"1596d43e",8:"d93f7b24",9:"7156fd72"}[e]+".js"}` in function which returns the list of the js files and `e=function(e){var t=[],a={1:1,3:1};r[e]?t.push(r[e]):0!==r[e]&&a[e]&&t.push(r[e]=new Promise((function(t,a){for(var n="static/spa/css/"+({}[e]||e)+"."+{1:"4ea14588",3:"534f7efb",4:"31d6cfe0",5:"31d6cfe0",6:"31d6cfe0",7:"31d6cfe0",8:"31d6cfe0",9:"31d6cfe0"}[e]+".css" // some code....` in function which returns the list of the css files. And it works for me. If there are another better solution, please, share me. It is not good solution, I think.